# How to use new irb in Rails 6 console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb

How to use the new `irb` when running `rails console` with Rails 6?

By new `irb`, I mean the one with the auto syntax highlighting, the dynamic `*` indicator on the prompt and so on.

I noticed this was the case just after upgrading to Rails 6, but somehow I'm back with *old* `irb` UX now (still multiline though).

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
gem 'irb'
```

to your Gemfile.

```
bundle update irb
```

and you are done.